# IoTAgent-LoRaWAN is apparently not working as expected

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion, lora, lorawan

I was trying to provisioning the IoTAgent-LoRaWAN using the TTN credentials, I'm following [the official docs](https://fiware-lorawan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users_manual/index.html#device-provisioning) and this is my POST request:

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "{{node}}",
      "entity_name": "LORA-N-0",
      "entity_type": "LoraDevice",
      "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "object_id": "potVal",
          "name": "Pot_Value",
          "type": "Number"
        }
      ],
      "internal_attributes": {
        "lorawan": {
          "application_server": {
            "host": "eu.thethings.network",
            "username": "{{TTN_app_id}}",
            "password": "{{TTN_app_pw}}",
            "provider": "TTN"
          },
          "dev_eui": "{{TTN_dev_eui}}",
          "app_eui": "{{TTN_app_eui}}",
          "application_id": "{{TTN_app_id}}",
          "application_key": "{{TTN_app_skey}}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Obviously I'm using Postman to manage all those HTTP requests in a collection and I've setup a few environment variables that are:

`{{node}}` -> the device ID `node_0`

`{{TTN_app_id}}` -> my app id which I've chosen `dendrometer`

`{{TTN_app_pw}}` -> the application access key shown in the picture (It can be found in the same view than the Application Overview; `https://console.thethingsnetwork.org/applications/<application_id>`)
[image]

`{{TTN_dev_eui}}` and `{{TTN_app_eui}}` also shown in the following picture (regarding to device; I think these are not sensitive info because TTN is not hiding them, that's because I'm posting the picture)

`{{TTN_app_skey}}` -> The Application Session Key also shown in the following picture (the last one)
[image]

The point is ... once I've provisioned IoTAgent using that request, the `docker-compose logs -f iot-agent` shows the following errors:

```
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.689Z","level":"info","message":"New message in topic"}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.690Z","level":"info","message":"IOTA provisioned devices:"}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.691Z","level":"info","message":"Decoding CaynneLPP message:+XQ="}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.691Z","level":"error","message":"Error decoding CaynneLPP message:Error: Invalid CayennLpp buffer size"}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.691Z","level":"error","message":"Could not cast message to NGSI"}
```

So I think there is something not working properly. That's my `docker-compose.yml`, btw http://ix.io/2pWd

However I don't think the problem is caused by docker, all containers are working as expected apparently because I can request their versions and I don't see error messages in the logs.

Also ... I feel [the docs](https://fiware-lorawan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users_manual/index.html) like incomplete, I'd like more info, about how to subscribe those provisioned devices with OrionCB (?) or Delete them (that's not shown in the docs, although is just a DELETE request to the proper URL.)

Anyway ... What I'm doing wrong? Thank you all.

EDIT: I feel like there is something wrong in the IoTAgent itself, there is a typo in the following error messages:

```
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.691Z","level":"info","message":"Decoding CaynneLPP message:+XQ="}
fiware-iot-agent | {"timestamp":"2020-06-23T11:45:53.691Z","level":"error","message":"Error decoding CaynneLPP message:Error: Invalid CayennLpp buffer size"}
```

Because it isn't CaynneLPP but CayenneLPP. I've also opened [an issue in its GitHub repo](https://github.com/Atos-Research-and-Innovation/IoTagent-LoRaWAN/issues/99) but I don't expect they answer any time soon. I actually feel like this project has been abandoned.

Comment: See my response in one of the other places you posted this: https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/cayennelpp-and-fiware-iot-agent-for-lorawan/38052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently a problem with encoding, I was using the encoding method suggested by [arduinio-lmic](https://github.com/mcci-catena/arduino-lmic#sflt16) library but FIWARE does work under CayenneLPP data model. So I'm going to try replace that encoding method.

Thank you all anyway and specially to @arjan